# Amazon OpenSearch Master Nodes JVM Memory pressure consistently increasing

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, jvm, opensearch

My Opensearch cluster Master Nodes JVM Memory pressure was constantly stable for a long time. A few days ago, it started to consistently increase.

[image: Master Nodes JVM Memory Pressure]

I want to understand why this is happening, and what might be the root cause for this increase? We have no changes in the cluster configuration.

Comment: it can depend on the indices/shards. Are you having more indices/shards than before? Or are the indices are not rotated or you are psuhing more data than before? You can check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-high-jvm-memory-pressure/ for more details.

Comment: No there was no change in the indices or shards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with AWS support, It turned out to be a regular behavior that happen when Master Node is changed, i.e., a new master node is elected.

Comment: So..there was a configuration change..

Comment: no, I didn't make any configuration change. This action was automatically done. Maybe due to JVM Memory pressure and CPU utilization.

Comment: Strange as I have seen every possible problem with aws managed ES/opensearch but never seen automatic change in master or data nodes. Anyway, glad your issue is resolved.